# regular expression help

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I need one regular expression pattern, in that i have to verify string contains at least one upper or lower case character or one number i dont have problem with position. if string contains only special charactors it will be invalid.
EX :

- `@#@#@#` - invalid string
- `!@$%^&a` - valid string
- `!@$$*)(&A` - valid string
- `!@$$*)(&1` - valid string

What pattern will work here?

```
String regExp = '([a-zA-Z0-9]*)';

String[] regExps = new string[]{'@#@#@#','@#@#@#a ','@#@#@#A','@#@#@#1'};



    for(string regEx : regExps)

{

    //system.debug('regEx== '+regEx);

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regExp).matcher(regEx);



    if(m.matches()) {

        System.debug(regEx);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not apply tags which have nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 2):

Please note from the documentation on the [`Matcher`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm) class that the `matches` method tells you if the pattern matches the entire string:

> **matches()**
>   Attempts to match the *entire region* against the pattern

So you are checking if the input sequence consists of *only* the character class you specify. You want instead to see if that character class appears at any point within the input sequence. You are looking for the `find()` method:

> **find()**
>   Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern. This method returns true if a *subsequence of the input sequence* matches this Matcher object's pattern.

Your snippet rewritten:

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9]');

String[] inputs = new String[]{'@#@#@#','@#@#@#a ','@#@#@#A','@#@#@#1'};
for(String input : inputs)
    if(myPattern.matcher(input).find())
        system.debug(input);
```

You could also verify your expected behavior according to your bullet list:

```
Pattern isValid = Pattern.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9]');
system.assert(!isValid.matcher('@#@#@#').find());
system.assert(isValid.matcher('@#@#@#a ').find());
system.assert(isValid.matcher('!@$$*)(&A').find());
system.assert(isValid.matcher('@#@#@#1').find());
```